# Weird Python Regex Issues

Tags: python, regex, unicode

```
whitespace_pattern = u"\s" # bug: tried to use unicode \u0020, broke regex

time_sig_pattern = \
    """^%(ws)s*time signature:%(ws)s*(?P<top>\d+)%(ws)s*\/%(ws)s*(?P<bottom>\d+)%(ws)s*$""" %{"ws": whitespace_pattern}


time_sig         = compile(time_sig_pattern,         U|M)
```

For some reason, adding the Verbose flag, X, to compile breaks the pattern.

Also, I wanted to use unicode for whitespace_pattern recognition (supposedly, we'll get patterns that use non-unicode spaces and we need to explicitly check for that one unicode character as a valid space), but the pattern keeps breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VERBOSE` gives you the ability to write comments in your regex to document it.

In order to do so, it ignores spaces, since you need to use line breaks to write comments.

Replace all spaces in your regex by `\s` to specify they are spaces you want to match in your pattern, and not just some spaces to format your comments.

What's more, you may want to use the `r` prefix for the string you use as a pattern. It tells Python not to interpret special notations such as `\n` and let you use backslashes without escaping them.

Answer (score 0):

Always define regexes with the `r` prefix to indicate they are raw strings.

```
 r"""^%(ws)s*time signature:%(ws)s*(?P<top>\d+)%(ws)s*\/%(ws)s*(?P<bottom>\d+)%(ws)s*$""" %{"ws": whitespace_pattern}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a regex to match unicode characters you do not want to use a Python unicode string.  In your example regular expression needs to see the literal characters `\u0020`, so you should use `whitespace_pattern = r"\u0020"` instead of `u"\u0020"`.

As other answers have mentioned, you should also use the `r` prefix for `time_sig_pattern`, after those two changes your code should work fine.

For `VERBOSE` to work correctly you need to escape all whitespace in the pattern, so towards the beginning of the pattern replace the space in `time signature` with `"\ "` (quotes for clarity), `\s`, or `[ ]` as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X).